# Add a button to middle of screen

Tags: html, css, wordpress

http://robertfabbri.com/ is the website.

I want to add a link in the middle of the home page which will link to a competition.

What would be the best way to do this?

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Do you want it always in the middle?

Comment: Adding a button to a website is straightforward.   There are many ways to do it that you can find with a Google search.   Are you have problems implementing one of them?  If so, please edit your question to include the code that isn't working and describe what is going wrong.

Answer (score 3):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/xy2Y7/2/)**

```
.button {
    position: fixed;
    margin: auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100px; /* width of button */
    height: 30px; /* height of button */
}
```

html

```
<button class="button">The button</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to center an element both vertically and horizontally, the best approach would be to add this:

```
.link { position:absolute; left:0; top:0; right:0; bottom:0; margin:auto; }
```

(Note: this only works if the .link element has a height and a width specified)

If you only want to center the element horizontally, the best way would be to do add a `display:inline` or `display:inline-block` to your link element, and a `text-align:center` to the parent of the link element.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the neatest method... I would go for a margin auto method... but this padding seems to do the job!

You may wish to specify the button width and or change the padding to approx 48% to counter the button width as the element is positioned via the top left corner... not the center.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.centdiv{
margin:auto;
width:100%;
padding:50%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="centdiv">
<button type="button" onclick="alert('Whoila!')">Click Me!</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: FYI This works dynamically, so for any sized screen resolution this will work and position in the center.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use CSS property:
"Position: absolute"

EXP:

// html
<div id="button">
  <a href="your link"><img src="image link" /></a>
</div>


//CSS
.home{position:relative;}
#button{position:absolute; top:50%; left:50%;}

may be this will help you.
```

Comment: do you think that the button will came in exact center of the center ?

Answer (score -1):

if you need always in middle you can use this css.

```
input {
    left: 50%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
}
```

you can use some class to your button and use it.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Qk7Vn/)

Comment: This works if the button is `0x0`.